# Changing to polar form for Green's Theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, polar-coordinates

In my text given the integral $\int_{\partial{D}} xy\,dx$, and that

$$\int_{\partial{D}} xy\,dx=-\int\int_{D}x\,dx\,dy = - \int\int r\cos \theta\,r\,dr\,d\theta$$

I'm not really understanding the change to polar, and how we get this result.

I see that $x=r\cos\theta$ but how does $dx \to r\,dr$ and $dy \to d\theta$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First equality holds via  [Green's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem)
$$\int_{\partial D} xy\, dx  = - \iint_{D} x d(x,y).$$

For the second one the substitution is made (polar coordinates)
\begin{cases} x= r\cos\theta \\ y= r\sin \theta.\end{cases}

Thus we obtain

$$- \iint_{D} x d(x,y) = -\int \int r\cos \theta |J| dr d\theta,$$
where $J$ is a Jacobian determinant of the coordinate conversion formula
$$J 
=\begin{vmatrix}
 \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} \\[8pt]
 \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}
\end{vmatrix}
=\begin{vmatrix}
 \cos\theta & -r\sin\theta \\
 \sin\theta & r\cos\theta
\end{vmatrix}
=r\cos^2\theta + r\sin^2\theta = r.$$

Therefore,
$$\int \int r\cos \theta |J| dr d\theta = \int \int r^2\cos \theta\, dr d\theta.$$

You should familiarise yourself with the formula for integration by substitution for multiple variables, [here is the link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables).